# Is there anyway to add a class to a specific node when using google orgchart API?

Tags: css, google-visualization, orgchart

I am using [google org chart API.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart)  I would like to style a particular node but i don't see anyway to add a className or an id on a specific node to then use css to style.

I see you can change the style on all nodes but i don't see anyway to do it on a single node

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set "style" and "selectedStyle" properties on the DataTable row for the node you want to style (see the [OrgChart custom properties](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart#customproperties)).

If you specifically need to use a class, then your only option is to set the formatted value of the cell to wrap the contents in a `<div>` with the desired class.

Comment: thanks . . how do i know what to put as the first argument?  In the example on the link does "3" represent the 3rd row?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify styling in JSON literal you can use the `p:{style: 'some styling here'}` property for the row object. However you cannot specify class definition in `p` attribute :(

JSON Example:

```
var dataAsJSON = {
      cols:[{type:'string'},{type:'string'},{type:'string'}],
      rows:[
        {c:[{v: '0', f: 'Final Fantasy'}, null, {v: 'First Root'}], p:{style: 'background-color:violet;'}},
        {c:[{v: '1', f: 'DmC'}, null, {v: 'Second Root'}], p:{style: 'background-color:lime;'}},
        {c:[{v: '2', f: 'Cloud Strife'}, {v: '0'}, null]},
        {c:[{v: '3', f: getFormattedCell('Vincent Valentine')}, {v: '0'}, null]},
        {c:[{v: '4', f: 'Sephiroth'}, {v: '2'}, null]},
        {c:[{v: '5', f: 'Dante'}, {v: '1'}, null]},
        {c:[{v: '6', f: 'Nero'}, {v: '1'}, null]}
      ]
    };
```